# Connecting to SQL Server in Php - Extension Err

Tags: php, sql-server, wampserver

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Connecting </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
    $host = "*.*.*.*";
 $username = "xxx";
 $password = "xxx";
 $db_name = "xxx";

    $db = mssql_connect($host, $username,$password)
    or die("Couldn't Connect");
 $selected = mssql_select_db($db_name, $db)
 or die("Couldn't open database");

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

My error message is:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in C:\wamp\www\php\dbase.php on line 12

I am using WampServer 2.0 on Php 5.3.0

When I check the extensions, php_mssql is Checked. I also checked the php.ini file to make sure it is not commented out.

I have my file dbase.php saved in C:\wamp\www\php. I have tried stopping the service, closing everything, and running it again. I know the problem is that the extension file is not being included somehow.

The below is copied from my php.ini file. *Note I made all http = /http to  avoid posting Links.*

> ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; ; Paths
>   and Directories ;
>   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
>
> ; UNIX: "/path1:/path2" ;include_path
>   = ".:/php/includes" ; Windows: "\path1;\path2" include_path =
>   "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext" ; ;
>   PHP's default setting for include_path
>   is ".;/path/to/php/pear" ;
>   /http://php.net/include-path
>
> ; The root of the PHP pages, used only
>   if nonempty. ; if PHP was not compiled
>   with FORCE_REDIRECT, you SHOULD set
>   doc_root ; if you are running php as a
>   CGI under any web server (other than
>   IIS) ; see documentation for security
>   issues.  The alternate is to use the ;
>   cgi.force_redirect configuration below
>   ; /http://php.net/doc-root doc_root =
>
> ; The directory under which PHP opens
>   the script using /~username used only
>   ; if nonempty. ;
>   /http://php.net/user-dir user_dir =
>
> ; Directory in which the loadable
>   extensions (modules) reside. ;
>   /http://php.net/extension-dir ;
>   extension_dir = "./" ; On windows: ;
>   extension_dir = "ext" extension_dir =
>   "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/"
>
> ; Whether or not to enable the dl()
>   function.  The dl() function does NOT
>   work ; properly in multithreaded
>   servers, such as IIS or Zeus, and is
>   automatically ; disabled on them. ;
>   /http://php.net/enable-dl enable_dl =
>   Off
>
> ; cgi.force_redirect is necessary to
>   provide security running PHP as a CGI
>   under ; most web servers.  Left
>   undefined, PHP turns this on by
>   default.  You can ; turn it off here
>   AT YOUR OWN RISK ; **You CAN safely
>   turn this off for IIS, in fact, you
>   MUST.** ;
>   /http://php.net/cgi.force-redirect
>   ;cgi.force_redirect = 1
>
> ; if cgi.nph is enabled it will force
>   cgi to always sent Status: 200 with ;
>   every request. PHP's default behavior
>   is to disable this feature. ;cgi.nph =
>   1
>
> ; if cgi.force_redirect is turned on,
>   and you are not running under Apache
>   or Netscape ; (iPlanet) web servers,
>   you MAY need to set an environment
>   variable name that PHP ; will look for
>   to know it is OK to continue
>   execution.  Setting this variable MAY
>   ; cause security issues, KNOW WHAT YOU
>   ARE DOING FIRST. ;
>   /http://php.net/cgi.redirect-status-env
>   ;cgi.redirect_status_env = ;
>
> ; cgi.fix_pathinfo provides *real*
>   PATH_INFO/PATH_TRANSLATED support for
>   CGI.  PHP's ; previous behaviour was
>   to set PATH_TRANSLATED to
>   SCRIPT_FILENAME, and to not grok ;
>   what PATH_INFO is.  For more
>   information on PATH_INFO, see the cgi
>   specs.  Setting ; this to 1 will cause
>   PHP CGI to fix its paths to conform to
>   the spec.  A setting ; of zero causes
>   PHP to behave as before.  Default is
>   1.  You should fix your scripts ; to use SCRIPT_FILENAME rather than
>   PATH_TRANSLATED. ;
>   /http://php.net/cgi.fix-pathinfo
>   ;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
>
> ; FastCGI under IIS (on WINNT based
>   OS) supports the ability to
>   impersonate ; security tokens of the
>   calling client.  This allows IIS to
>   define the ; security context that the
>   request runs under.  mod_fastcgi under
>   Apache ; does not currently support
>   this feature (03/17/2002) ; Set to 1
>   if running under IIS.  Default is
>   zero. ;
>   /http://php.net/fastcgi.impersonate
>   ;fastcgi.impersonate = 1;
>
> ; Disable logging through FastCGI
>   connection. PHP's default behavior is
>   to enable ; this feature.
>   ;fastcgi.logging = 0
>
> ; cgi.rfc2616_headers configuration
>   option tells PHP what type of headers
>   to ; use when sending HTTP response
>   code. If it's set 0 PHP sends Status:
>   header that ; is supported by Apache.
>   When this option is set to 1 PHP will
>   send ; RFC2616 compliant header. ;
>   Default is zero. ;
>   /http://php.net/cgi.rfc2616-headers
>   ;cgi.rfc2616_headers = 0
>
> ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; ; File Uploads ;
>   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
>
> ; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
>   ; /http://php.net/file-uploads
>   file_uploads = On
>
> ; Temporary directory for HTTP
>   uploaded files (will use system
>   default if not ; specified). ;
>   /http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
>   upload_tmp_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
>
> ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded
>   files. ;
>   /http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
>   upload_max_filesize = 2M

Also, my php.ini file is saved in: C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem and the solution is quite simple. The default driver in PHP 5.3 for MS SQL Server does not work anymore in Windows. Microsoft has released a driver that you can use. The driver comes with documentation.

Here is the link where you can find the download: http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/

Here is the link where you can find some documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296172(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe php is using another ini file like C:\windows\php.ini, it has happen to me in the past :)

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are using PHP 5.3 would it not make more sense to use the PDO Objects? Like so:

```
<?php

class DatabaseConn {

    static function createNewMySQLConnection() {

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . MYSQL_DB_DATA . "; host=" . MYSQL_DB_HOST, MYSQL_DB_USER, MYSQL_DB_PASS);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $x = new MyException("Failed to connect to db: " . $e->getMessage());
            $x->errorMessage();
            return null;
        }

        $conn->beginTransaction();

        return $conn;
    }

    static function createNewPgSQLConnection() {

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=" . PGSQL_DB_DATA . "; host=" . PGSQL_DB_HOST, PGSQL_DB_USER, PGSQL_DB_PASS);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $x = new MyException("Failed to connect to db: " . $e->getMessage());
            $x->errorMessage();
            return null;
        }

        $conn->beginTransaction();

        return $conn;
    }

    static function createNewMsSQLConnection() {

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("dblib:dbname=" . MSSQL_DB_DATA . "; host=" . MSSQL_DB_HOST, MSSQL_DB_USER, MSSQL_DB_PASS);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $x = new MyException("Failed to connect to db: " . $e->getMessage());
            $x->errorMessage();
            return null;
        }

        $conn->beginTransaction();

        return $conn;
    }

    static function runExecute($conn, $query) {

        try {

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query->sql);
            if (isset($query->input) && !is_null($query->input)) {
                $stmt->execute($query->input);
                return true;
            } else {
                $stmt->execute();
                return true;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            if (isset($query->input)) {

                $inputs = "";
                foreach ($query->input as $i) {
                    $inputs .= "'" . $i . "' ";
                }
                $msg = "$query->sql with input(s) $inputs. statement failed, rolling back: " . $e->getMessage();
            } else {
                $msg = "$query->sql . statement failed, rolling back: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
            $x = new MyException($msg);
            $x->errorMessage();
        }
        return false;
    }

    static function runPreparedQuery($conn, $query) {

        $results = null;
        try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query->sql);
            if (isset($query->input) && !is_null($query->input)) {
                $stmt->execute($query->input);
            } else {
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            if (isset($query->input)) {

                $inputs = "";
                foreach ($query->input as $i) {
                    $inputs .= "'" . $i . "' ";
                }
                $msg = "$query->sql with input(s) $inputs. statement failed, rolling back: " . $e->getMessage();
            } else {

                $msg = "$query->sql . statement failed, rolling back: " . $e->getMessage();
            }

            $x = new MyException($msg);
            $x->errorMessage();

            return null;
        }

        return $results;
    }

    static function getLastInsertId($conn) {
        return $conn->lastInsertId();
    }

    static function closeConn($conn, $commit) {

        if ($commit) {
            $conn->commit();
        } else {
            $conn->rollBack();
        }

        $conn = null;
    }

}
?>
```

It's not perfect but it works for me